# node mysql's connection pool query callbacks are never called

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, node-mysql

Has anyone run into an issue with mysql where pooled query callbacks are never called?

I’m creating a pool and then using it to execute multiple queries like this:

```
const mysql = require('mysql')

const config = {
    mysql: {host: ..., user: ..., password: ...},
    ...
}

config.mysql.connectionLimit = 20
let pool = mysql.createPool(config.mysql)

...further down in my test code

const toDelete = [
    'test_db_2017-03-22_11-10-21',
    'test_db_2017-03-21_11-10-21',
    'test_db_2016-03-21_11-10-21',
    'test_db_2015-03-21_11-10-21',
    'test_db_2014-03-21_11-10-21',
    'test_db_2013-03-21_11-10-21',
]


const deleteTargetsCreated = toDelete.map(dbname => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        pool.getConnection((error, connection) => {
            if(error) return reject(error)

            connection.query(`CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS \`${dbname}\``, (error, rows, fields) => {
                connection.release()
                if(error) return reject()
                resolve()
            })
        })
    })
})

Promise.all(deleteTargetsCreated).then(...).catch(...)
```

I'm never getting to the callback for the `connection.query` call. I'm also not getting any error messages, it's like something is failing silently that I'm missing.

I'm using the mysql bundle at version 2.14.0.